# Array length doesn't change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

hey so i use express and everytime a req is made i don't respond to it and store it in an array (to long poll)

like this: `{ req, res }`

but if i try multiple tabs the length stays 1 until one is responded to
why does this happen?
like, i could have 5 tabs (and realistically 5 reqs in the array) but only when i respond to one, another one appears (until all are answered)

code:

```js
const reqs = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  reqs.push({ "req": req, "res": res });
  console.log(reqs.length); // 0 if none; but only 1 no matter how many requests are pending a response
});
```

i tried looping the reqs too using different for loops but only 1 responds per run of the function (manually ran)
it's weird
it's like node doesn't know the other reqs exist
is it because the array get's too big
orrr?

Comment: The code in your question should not produce that behavior. Are you sure that's your *exact* code? I think you may have over-simplified.

Comment: @Certainperformance it's been simplified, but that's exactly how i add it to the array.

Comment: That exact code should not produce the error you describe.

Comment: Please try to create a new project with example you provides and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

> but if i try multiple tabs the length stays 1 until one is responded to why does this happen? like, i could have 5 tabs (and realistically 5 reqs in the array) but only when i respond to one, another one appears (until all are answered)

This behavior sounds like the browser is withholding sending the subsequent requests until the previous one has responded.  This is because these are identical requests to the same host, same URL and might be cacheable responses.  You can see how the browser would benefit if three different parts of the page all requested the same image.  The browser sends one request for the image, then waits for it before deciding what to do with the other identical requests.  If the response comes back and is cacheable, then the browser can just use that image response to handle the subsequent requests, saving time and resources and improving performance of both client and server.

You can bypass this behavior by adding a variable query string to the URL (something that is different for each request) or by setting the right things on the request to say you don't want caching (an option for the `fetch()` interface for example).

For example, if each subsequent request is different:

```
/?i=1
/?i=2
/?i=3
```

Then, the browser will send all three without waiting for the first one to respond before sending the second one.

Keep in mind that a browser also has a limit on how many simultaneous requests can be in flight to the same host (regardless of the URL) so you may also eventually run into that limit, but that value is typically something like 6, not 1 as you are experiencing.  So, what you are experiencing is probably because the URLs for the different requests are all identical.

If you are sending these requests in the browser with the `fetch()` interface, then you can use the `{ cache: "no-store" }` option to tell `fetch()` not to look in the cache or wait for the cache.

Answer (score -1):

You are sending req and res variables in a single object to reqs which means that reqs has only one object in it which is `{"req": $req, "res": $res}`.

If u want to provide multiple objects, Pls try in this way

```
const express = require('express')

const reqs = [];

const app = express()

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  reqs.push( {"req": req});
  reqs.push( {"res": res });
  res.send("Hello World")
  console.log(reqs.length); // Will gives u 2 in this case as I have sent 2 objects into reqs , rather than one
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Hope, this is helpful to you.

Comment: That's not what i really meant.

Comment: Sry, U mean when every time, the user reloads the page, there will be a new object created in reqs right? Pls correct it if I am wrong.

Comment: No. I open a tab, go to the page, the length goes to 0 from 1. then i open another, but it stays on 1 until i respond to the first one. unless if the page is on a different device then it goes to 2.

Comment: Also in my case, the array length is changing every time when I reload the home page. Please try this                                                                                           
 {app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  reqs.push( {"req": req});
  res.send("Hello World")
  console.log(reqs.length);
});

app.listen(3000)}                                                                                                                              I think yours is not working because,  u are not reloading home page "/" for to js to execute the get function to push the object into reqs

Comment: The thing it is working for me on the same device. The count is going up when I reload the page.

Comment: i don't want to end the request. i want to answer it in a future time.

Comment: Hi, I think as it is reloading and waiting for the response and when u try to open the new tab in the same browser, rather than going back to the server, as this instance is still running (waiting to get the response) in another tab, it is taking this instance to the new tab. If u try closing the tab which is waiting for a response and open it again, the count again adds up. Sry it is what I can think of at the moment as I recall that browser/server relationship works in that way